# MInimum Spanning Tree and Combinatorics

Tags: weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

I just got a small confusion here,
I have a graph for which i need to get number of minimum spanning tree,
[image]

So, in graph i have 3 edges with weight 2 and 4 edges with weight 3,
in such a way that AE = AB = BE = 2 and ED = DC = EC = BC = 3.
The solution provided is 3C2*(2+3C2).

Initially taking any 2 edges from edges with weight 2 and then if BC is choosen then we can only take two edges ED and DC or else we can take edges from 3 weightes edges in 3C2 way respectively.

So, total number of MST possible is 15, but my doubt is, will the above solution include the possibility of forming a closed form from, AE-ED-DC-BC-AB ? as here i can see 2 edges from 2 weighted edges and 2 edges from 3 weighted edges, i am assuming BC is there as i cant see any condition stopping it.

Comment: A MST will have $n-1$ edges for $n$ vertices.

Comment: @RinkeshP Thanks Rinkesh, i know that fact, but i was just trying to convince myself that will not the combinatoric solution include that closed form.

Comment: No combinatoric solution will include more than $n-1$ edges as its in the definition of MST. Any algorithm you run will terminate once it finds $n-1$ edges.

Comment: T stands for tree.

Answer (score 0):

AE-ED-DC-BC-AB contains $5$ edges, when the solutions you counted contained $4$ edges (rightly so), so there is indeed $15$ solutions, and AE-ED-DC-BC-AB is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mis-understanding the interpretation of the solution. ${3 \choose 2} (2 + {3 \choose 2})$ is the sum of the two distinct cases you cases you pointed out.

In both cases, 2 edges from $\{AB, AE, BE\}$ are chosen. This is in accordance with algorithms such as Prim's for greedily constructing MSTs. This can be done in ${3 \choose 2}$ ways. After this step, vertices $A, B, E$ are connected. We then move on to selecting edges of weight 3.

**Case 1**

If $BC$ is part of the MST, we must choose one last edge to connect vertex $D$ to the tree. There are only two options - $ED$ and $DC$. Thus, there are ${3 \choose 2} \cdot 2$ possibilities.

**Case 2**

If $BC$ is not part of the MST, there are 3 viable edges of which any two will connect $D$ and $E$ to the tree without creating a cycle. Thus, there are ${3 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 2}$ possibilities.

In total, we then get the expected ${3 \choose 2} (2 + {3 \choose 2})$ number of MSTs. In particular, receiving an MST given by $\{AE, ED, DC, BC, AB\}$ is not possible because both cases we covered above only choose 4 edges. In general, a tree on $n$ vertices has exactly $n-1$ edges. Case 1 above considers $BC$ to be part of the MST then considers the possibilities where $\{BC, DE\}$ or $\{BC, CD\}$ are added to the existing MST, not $\{BC, DE, CD\}$.

Hope this helps!